# save 5 columns of one table into 5 rows in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, rows, multiple-columns

I have a table Items having a unique id: itemId, …
Example of  a row: ‘3506’, …

I have a table ItemProperties with the following columns:
itemId, datecreated, datemodified, property1, property2, property3, property4, property5

example of a row: ‘3506’, ‘2012…’, ‘2012…’, ‘prop1’, ‘prop2’, ‘prop3’, ‘prop4’, ‘prop5’

I need to split every row of the ItemProperties table into 5 separate rows in the NewItemProperties table with the following columns:
itemId, datecreated, datemodified, propertynumber, property

example of the 5 rows:

```
‘3506’, ‘2012…’, ‘2012…’, 1, ‘prop1’

‘3506’, ‘2012…’, ‘2012…’, 2, ‘prop2’

‘3506’, ‘2012…’, ‘2012…’, 3, ‘prop3’

‘3506’, ‘2012…’, ‘2012…’, 4, ‘prop4’

‘3506’, ‘2012…’, ‘2012…’, 5, ‘prop5’
```

Constraints:
-        ItemProperties with an itemId that is no longer in the Items table should not be processed

- Items that are already in the NewItems table(id =id and propertynumber=number of property1~5 column) should not be overwritten/updated by this process
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- Around 800000 rows in the ItemProperties table

Very slow solution I have at this moment:

...

```
DECLARE c CURSOR read_only FOR SELECT * from ItemProperties

DECLARE @ID varchar(14), @CREA datetime, …

OPEN  c     

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @CREA, @MODI, @COL, @SIZE, @PAT, @YEAR, @ITEM

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)

BEGIN

    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)

    BEGIN
         select * from Items where itemId = @ID
         if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
               BEGIN
                    GOTO Fetch_Next
               END
         select * from ItemProperties where itemId = @ID AND propertynumber = 1
         if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
               INSERT INTO NewItemProperties
               VALUES(@ID, '1', @COL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
         select * from ItemProperties where itemId = @ID AND propertynumber = 2
         if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
               INSERT INTO NewItemProperties
               VALUES(@ID, '2', @SIZE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
     …

      END
    Fetch_Next:
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @CREA, @MODI, @COL, @SIZE, @PAT, @YEAR, @ITEM
...
```

I can optimize my fetch statement by removing the creation and modification dates but that is about all I can come up with. I could not fit this into an unpivot query. Basically anything that is faster then a cursor will help me out. All ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: A combination of `unpivot` and `merge` should work. Unpivot to make the source the same shape as the destination, and then merge to push the new bits over.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO NewItemProperties
SELECT itemId, '1', property1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM ItemProperties 
UNION ALL
SELECT itemId, '2', property2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM ItemProperties
......
UNION ALL
SELECT itemId, '5', property5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM ItemProperties
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure why you stated that you could not get this to fit in an `UNPIVOT`. But you should be able to use an `UNPIVOT` to transform your data and then insert it into the new table.  You can add any `WHERE` clause conditions on the inner query.  The key to the `UNPIVOT` is that the data be of the same datatype, so if needed you might have to cast the data in the subquery to the same datatype:

```
insert into NewItemProperties(yourCcolsHere)
select itemid,
  datecreated, 
  datemodified,
  replace(col, 'property', '') col,
  value
from
(
 -- perform any datatype conversions here
  select i.itemid,
    p.datecreated,
    p.datemodified,
    p.property1, 
    p.property2, 
    p.property3, 
    p.property4, 
    p.property5
  from items i
  inner join ItemProperties p
    on i.itemid = p.itemid
) src
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (property1, property2, property3,
              property4, property5)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51251/2)

The `UNPIVOT` function performs the same function as a `UNION ALL` query:

```
insert into NewItemProperties(yourCcolsHere)
select i.itemid,
    p.datecreated,
    p.datemodified,
    1 PropNumber,
    p.property1 value 
from items i
inner join ItemProperties p
  on i.itemid = p.itemid
union all
select i.itemid,
    p.datecreated,
    p.datemodified,
    2 PropNumber,
    p.property2 value
from items i
inner join ItemProperties p
  on i.itemid = p.itemid -- add more queries for the other properties
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51251/4)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by defining a query that returns everything to insert, and then inserting them:

```
with toinsert as (
     select ip.itemid, datecreated, datemodified, num as propertynumber
            (case when num = 1 then property1
                  when num = 2 then property2
                  when num = 3 then property3
                  when num = 4 then property4
                  when num = 5 then property5
             ) as property
     from ItemProperties ip cross join
          (select 1 as num union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
          ) nums left outer join
          NewItemProperties nip
          on ip.itemid = nip.itemid and
             nums.num = nip.propertynumber
     where nip.itemid is null
    )
insert into NewItemProperties (itemid, datecreated, datemodified, propertynumber, property)
    select *
    from toinsert
```